# Extract sentences using regexpr in R

Tags: r, regex, nlp

From a body of text, I would like to extract a sentence that starts with the word "Meds:" with regular expressions. I pattern that I used was:

```
    "[:blank:]Meds:[^.]*\\."
```

so that my sentence would start just before the word "Meds:" followed by more words and end at the period. It didn't work the way I hoped it would.

Here's what happened:

```
[1] Patient X came with the complain of pain Meds:ASA 81mg PO qd, 
toprol XL 25 mg PO Gen: Healthy appearing, overweight.
```

1. My output didn't start at the word "Meds:" rather a whole sentence before it and continued to the next sentence until it matched the next 'period'. So it looked like this:
2. I would like it to stop at '25 mg PO' but I understand that it didn't do so because it couldn't find a 'period' there.

   Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Modifying the pattern to    "[\\s]Meds:[^.]*\\."  took care of starting with the word "Meds:" though i still need to figure out how to stop where I would like it to stop (given the absence of period)

Comment: what's the stopping condition?

Comment: I doubt there is a way to split this text ibto sentences, as there is no formal means delimiting them.

Comment: @SandipanDey I would like it to stop when the medication list ends i.e., at PO but just like Wiktor mentioned, there's no special/formal character that marks the end of the list, rather its just a space.

Comment: yes i guessed that, the regex posted should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
text = 'Patient X came with the complain of pain Meds:ASA 81mg PO qd, toprol XL 25 mg PO Gen: Healthy appearing, overweight.'
gsub(".*(Meds:[^.:]*)\\s+[^:]+:.*" , '\\1', text)
# [1] "Meds:ASA 81mg PO qd, \ntoprol XL 25 mg PO"
```

Answer (score -1):

Heres one way you can do it:

```
\sMeds:([^.:]*)\s\w+:
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/F52qFz/2)